# Разграничение прав доступа на сайте

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Вопрос заключается в следующем... Как реализовать вход по роли к сайту?

Есть роль пользователь и оператор , мне нужно чтобы при входе открывалась определенная страница для пользователя и определенная для оператора.

Как можно это сделать?

Мой код:

```php
$_SESSION['operator'] -> Оператор
$_SESSION['polz'] -> Пользователь

if ($_SESSION['operator'])
{
  //При выполнении этого условия, должен располагаться, код, контент доступный только "Оператору"
  header('Location: ../mainpageoper.php');
}
elseif ($_SESSION['polz'])
{
  //При выполнении этого условия, должен располагаться, код, контент доступный только "Пользователю"
  header('Location: ../mainpagepolz.php');
}
if( [role] == 1 ) { $_SESSION['polz'] = 1; }
if( [role] == 2 ) { $_SESSION['operator'] = 1; }
```

В итоге сделал так и переходы согласно роли происходят :

```
    if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 1):
        header('Location: ../mainpagepolz.php');
    elseif ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 2):
        header('Location: ../mainpageoper.php');
    else:
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Не верный логин или пароль';
        header('Location: ../auth.php');
    endif;
```

Comment: Создать на бекенде ролевую структуру, а на фронте условную отрисовку и route guards

Comment: @AndreyFreiz  
все страницы сверстал , но не смог найти ответ на вопрос. конкретно как это сделать на php.
Т.е. допустим роль пользователя= 1 , а оператор = 2

Comment: такое реализовывать лучше на фронт фреймворке где есть отрисовка по условию, и если роли 1 то отрисовываем одни блоки если другая то другие, так же и со страницами, на какие-то можно только 1 роли входить, а другим выводить нет доступа

Comment: @AndreyFreiz
отредактировал вопрос. типо такого?

Comment: я выше описал с целом ответ, когда будет много и зависит от того на чем пишется фронт

Comment: У вас два условия if, которые проверют роль текущего юзера и далее header, в нем вы редиректите юзера на нужную якобы страницу, вот сделайте 2 разных файла, в первом будет редирект на operator_role_html.php, а вот втором polz_role_html.php, там будет разный html под разных юзеров в каждом соответственно.

Comment: @Borislav ,ну собственно я так и думал сделать,  обращение к бд , таблице и полю "role"(1-2), если 1 то mainpagepolz.php,2 mainpageoper.php

Comment: @Borislav  подобную реализацию нашел ```$name = $_SESSION['name'];  
//Проверяем зашел ли пользователь  
if($user === false) 
{   
   echo '<h3>Доступ закрыт, Вы не вошли в систему!</h3>'."\n";  
}
 if($user === true) 
 {    
   //  
   echo "$name"; 
   switch($name) 
   { 
       case 'Пользователь': header ('Location: ../mainpagepolz.php');  
       break; 
       case 'Оператор': header ('Location: ../mainpageoper.php');  
       break;   
    }   
}```

Comment: @Grovli да, так можно сделать, но посмотрите лучше на реализацию шаблонизаторов, чтобы не использовать location. А в действительности, можете изучить фреймворк, который писал давно в целях обучения сам, там много комментариев и неплохих подходов, как организовать доступ по ролям, вес ролей, рендеринг и роутиг: https://gitlab.com/Zendden/zendden-framework/-/tree/master/app/core

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 1):
        header('Location: ../mainpagepolz.php');
    elseif ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 2):
        header('Location: ../mainpageoper.php');
    else:
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Не верный логин или пароль';
        header('Location: ../auth.php');
    endif;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]